# Diff since Nth byte for large file backup

Tags: backup, diff, incremental-backup, rdiff-backup

I've a hundreds of very large files (500GB+) that I've to sync daily to an external server.

These files are peculiar because they only change/append after the 99% of the file.

Hence I was wondering if it was possible to calculate and send a .diff (or patch in any other way) to the external server instead of having to read/checksum the entirety of files on client and server.

Comment: Meta note: Unless it's about non-\*nix, the question can be considered a cross-site duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/638231/108618). This is [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310). I note you did not blatantly copied and pasted; still it seems the problem is the same and for \*nix I cannot imagine an answer that would answer one question but not the other. IMO it's a cross-site duplicate. Or maybe this question is e.g. for Windows? This would make a difference. You should specify the OS(s) anyway ([edit] the question).

Comment: Research what `btrfs send` (`man btrfs-send`) and `btrfs receive` (`man btrfs-receive`) can do, [incremental operation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup#Incremental_Operation) in particular. I have experience with Btrfs but not with `btrfs send`, so it's just my guess it may help. It would require using Btrfs on both sides. I can imagine other reasons you may not want this approach. It can create updated file(s) cheaply, but you may want to update exact files on the server, i.e. files with exact inode numbers under exact mountpoints, without breaking hardlinks etc.